# Spring Boot in JDeveloper 12c

Tags: spring-boot, jdeveloper

I am able to successfully compile a Spring boot starter project developed in Eclipse and imported to Jdeveloper 12c using command line Maven. However, the Jdeveloper IDE compile is failing since it's unable to find the Springs tags and packages.

Any idea regarding the compile error.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue. The dependencies needed be in the dependency section of POM for Jdeveloper 12c to detect the jar files needed for the IDE compile. 
Some helpful links for deploying Spring Boot application in Weblogic:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html
http://www.virtual7.de/blog/2016/07/spring-boot-oracle-weblogic-server-12/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. The dependencies needed be in the dependency section of POM for Jdeveloper 12c to detect the jar files needed for the IDE compile. 
Some helpful links for deploying Spring Boot application in Weblogic:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html
http://www.virtual7.de/blog/2016/07/spring-boot-oracle-weblogic-server-12/